# trac roadmap progress bar

Tags: trac

I've recently migrated a trac project to a new machine and now the roadmap progress bars are not displayed. I've tried enabling and disabling RoadmapModule under the Admin -> General -> Plugins -> Trac 0.12.3 menu. I've also checked the project file trac.ini contains:

```
[milestone]
stats_provider = DefaultTicketGroupStatsProvider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was missing plug-in causing compatibility issues.

```
sudo easy_install -U -Z http://trac-hacks.org/svn/typedticketworkflowplugin/0.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Only progress bars? Than I guess it's an issue with CSS.

Double-check, that i.e. you have appropriate read permission and no interfering `style.css` in your `<env>/htdocs` directory.

Or you experience plugin issues, as later comments suggest. Disabling any plugin should bring you into a working state again. From there you can enable plugins step-by-step to find the interfering code, and maybe look for fixed/updated plugin code.

Comment: The permissions are the same on both the working instance and the new instance. If I view the source of new instance roadmap the html for the progress bars is not there, only the milestone and due date are displayed.

Comment: Ok, just added another suggestion. Note, that it can't be strictly a 'missing plugin' issue, because we speak about Trac core functionality. However an *updated* plugin might be another way to go, sure.